# Design issue when navigating side menu hamburger icon in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

My side menu is open all the time, when it is open, I show close button but the button is not proper.

The same occurs when my side menu is close which in turn shows the hamburger icon, that button is also not proper.

There are three lines for a hamburger icon, the middle one gets misaligned.

Refer code below:
[Icon transition issue](https://jsfiddle.net/16fgdjLs/)

```js
    const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
    let menuOpen = false;
    menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if(!menuOpen) {
        menuBtn.classList.add('open');
        menuOpen = true;
      } else {
        menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
        menuOpen = false;
      }
    });
```

```css
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      background: #272727;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }
    .menu-btn {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
      transform: translateX(0px);
      content: '';
      /* border: 3px solid #fff; */
    }
    .menu-btn__burger {
      width: 50px;
      height: 6px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
    .menu-btn__burger::before,
    .menu-btn__burger::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 6px;
      background: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
     transform: translateX(-50px);
    }
    .menu-btn__burger::before {
      transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
    }
    .menu-btn__burger::after {
      transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
    }
    /* ANIMATION */
    .menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
      transform: translateX(0px);
      background: transparent;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
    .menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
        transform: translateY(16px);
    }
    .menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
        transform: translateY(-16px);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>CSS Hamburger Animation</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="menu-btn">
        <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
      </div>
      <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should move the .menu-btn.open class, for more details, see the improvements I made even though it didn't change many things

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.menu-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  content: "";
  /* border: 3px solid #fff; */
}
.menu-btn__burger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn__burger::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255, 101, 47, 0.2);
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
  position: absolute;
}
/* ANIMATION */
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: translateY(16px);
}
.menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: translateY(-16px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You reversed your `CSS code`. When `.open` class is added then close Hamburger icon will be animated. And the position of the `Close icon` was not correct.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(!menuOpen) {
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
    menuOpen = true;
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
    menuOpen = false;
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.menu-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  /* border: 3px solid #fff; */
}
.menu-btn__burger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}
.menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn__burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 transform: translateX(-50px);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
/* ANIMATION */
.menu-btn .menu-btn__burger {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.menu-btn .menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: translateY(16px);
}
.menu-btn .menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: translateY(-16px);
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
  background: transparent;
}

.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
    left: -50px;
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>CSS Hamburger Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually wanted the reverse one.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that you were having trouble with the middle line disappearing when closed, and appearing off to the side when open, I have the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/nickberliner1/cLt8h3aj/3/.

The background of the middle line was transparent on closed, instead of on open.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background: #272727;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.menu-btn {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-50px);
  /* border: 3px solid #fff; */
}
.menu-btn__burger {
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn__burger::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 6px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
 transform: translateX(-50px);
}
.menu-btn__burger::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(35px, -35px);
}
.menu-btn__burger::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(35px, 35px);
}
/* ANIMATION */
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
  transform: translateX(0px);
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,101,47,.2);
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: translateY(16px);
}
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: translateY(-16px);
}
```

Comment: It is moving 50px ahead when clicking on hamburger button and vice-versa.